# Trying to copy a list in list python to a new structure but failing to do so, same works with normal list. Please suggest the same for list of list

Tags: python, list

```
import copy
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
actualtable=[]

actualtable =copy.copy(tableData)
tableData[0][0]='banana'


print(tableData)
print(actualtable)
```

Why does both the lists tableData and actualtable point to the same structure. Can someone help me out!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: that screenshot looks pretty cool, could you tell me where it's from? btw, if you replace `[Screenshot][1]` by `![Screenshot][1]`, you can embed the screenshot instead of only linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using a shallow `copy`, use `deepcopy` to get a different reference to list elements:

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

> copy.copy(x)
>
> Return a shallow copy of x.
>
> copy.deepcopy(x[, memo])
>
> Return a deep copy of x.

so in your code just replace `copy.copy` with `copy.deepcopy`:

```py
actualtable = copy.deepcopy(tableData)
```

and you'll get two entirely  different list of lists